# R character/string: '...' vs "..."

Tags: r, character

To declare a character or a string on R, one can use both following ways:

```
x <- 'Some string'
x <- "Some string"
```

Both work, but is there any difference ?

Comment: There's probably not much difference to what you find here: https://www.google.com/#q=programming+define+string+double+or+single+quotes

Comment: `"someone's"` vs `'someone"s'`

Comment: So it is exactly the same, only depending on what is the content of the string?

Comment: Also, single quote is just one key `'`, while double quote is 2 keys `SHIFT+2`

Comment: @zx8754 Depends on the Keyboard Layout.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From `?"'"`:

> Details
>
> Three types of quotes are part of the syntax of R: single and double
>   quotation marks and the backtick (or back quote, `). In addition,
>   backslash is used to escape the following character inside character
>   constants.
>
> Character constants
>
> **Single and double quotes delimit character constants. They can be used
>   interchangeably but double quotes are preferred** (and character
>   constants are printed using double quotes), so single quotes are
>   normally only used to delimit character constants containing double
>   quotes.
>
> Backslash is used to start an escape sequence inside character
>   constants. Escaping a character not in the following table is an
>   error.
>
> Single quotes need to be escaped by backslash in single-quoted
>   strings, and double quotes in double-quoted strings.

Answer (score 3):

No. These are identical.
......

Comment: Well... One is a quotation mark while the second is an apostrophe :)

Comment: Identical in the sense that they are matched.